# script written according to instructions however, i get unexpected end of line

Tags: shell

Error returned:

```
cgheonea@sd-76777:~$ /bin/bash -n monitor.sh
monitor.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

When executing the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
MOVIES="/tmp/movies"

declare -a format=("mkv" "mp4" "avi" "mpg" "mpeg")
declare -a lang=("en" "it" "es")

inotifywait -m -r -e close_write "$MOVIES" --format "%w%f" | while read fm;
do
    EXTENSION=${fm##*.}
    for i in "${format[@]}"
    do
      if [[ "$EXTENSION" = "$i" ]]; then
        for x in "${lang[@]}"
        do
          python /usr/local/bin/subliminal download -l $x $fm
        done
      fi
    done
done
```

Fixed.
The above works.

Comment: What is the symptom exactly? Please update the question rather than adding comments to clarify points.

Comment: This code as shown has no syntax error. It also has no line 22. Please show us the actual code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which is immediately apparent is that the [array syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) is wrong. Bash array elements are not comma separated, they are whitespace separated. So the `language` values are literally "es,", "en," and "it".

And `uset` should be `unset`.

Comment: Hi Lobo, I updated the code in the question and corrected the errors found. However, the issues found are not the cause of the script failure. Any future assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks mate.